# My allergy-caused stuffy nose goes away when I exercise. Why?

Tags: exercise, allergy, nose

I'm currently dealing with my seasonal pollen allergies, and currently the right side of my nose is simultaneously blocked and runny. But when I start exercising, for example five situps, the blockage clears right up and I can breathe clearly. If I stop exercising, it comes back as suddenly as it left. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [exercise causes your nasal membranes](http://www.entnet.org/content/stuffy-nose) to constrict helping you breathe easier. After you exercise the effects wear off and the symptoms return.

> Membranes in the nose have an abundant supply of arteries, veins, and
>   capillaries, which have the ability to expand and constrict. Normally
>   these blood vessels are in a half-constricted or half-open state. But
>   when a person exercises vigorously, hormone (adrenaline) levels
>   increase. Adrenaline causes constriction of the nasal membranes so
>   that the air passages open up and the person breathes freely.
>
> The opposite takes place when an allergic attack or a cold develops.
>   During a cold, blood vessels expand, membranes become congested, and
>   the nose becomes stuffy, or blocked.
>
> In addition to allergies and infections, certain circumstances can
>   cause nasal blood vessels to expand, leading to vasomotor rhinitis.

[fitnessandwellnessnews.com](http://fitnessandwellnessnews.com/work-out-sinus-pressure/), also make a valid argument. However, there's pertains less to the situation.

> Exercise can temporarily relieve nasal congestion. The increase in
>   circulation clears sinus pressure and allows for easier breathing. An
>   aerobic workout is especially successful in clearing congestion with
>   its cardio focus. Although you may want to blend in with the bedding,
>   movement provides the best relief.  A stuffed nose is worse when lying
>   down. Sinuses don’t have gravity working with them to drain cavities
>   blocked by mucus. Sinus congestion is also loosened by increased
>   temperature in the body’s core. A runny nose may ensue, which,
>   although annoying, relieves sinus pressure and stuffiness.

Comment: +1 for information, I am suffering from this since 10 years and its weird problem, i have to suffer in office infront of Air conditioner and also in night time, after bath, and also when i do not wear shocks and touch my feet on cold floor.
`does this problem having any solution ?`
I am really disturb with this allergy.